# setting blur layout on recycler view items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am using this [library](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewHover) when i click one of items the toast msz in it appears but the layout which i want to set on that doesn't appear nor any error message appears i don't know what i am doing wrong...help me out!

my layout [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Eagy.png/%22image%22)

**this is my adapter code:**

```
class LessonDataHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public BlurLayout samplelayout;
    private TextView nameOfSlip;
    private ImageView slipImage;
    private Context context;


    public LessonDataHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        context = itemView.getContext();
        nameOfSlip = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.demoText);
        slipImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewDemoVideo);
        samplelayout = (BlurLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.blur_layout);

        slipImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void bindSlip(VideoList videoList) {
        nameOfSlip.setText(videoList.stringSlipName);
        slipImage.setImageResource(videoList.stringImage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (view.getId() == slipImage.getId()) {

            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Chapter = " + String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()+1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            BlurLayout.setGlobalDefaultDuration(1000);

            View hover4 = LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.hover_card_view, null);
            samplelayout.setHoverView(hover4);
            samplelayout.setBlurDuration(2000);

            samplelayout.addChildAppearAnimator(hover4, R.id.hover_play_video, Techniques.SlideInRight);
            samplelayout.addChildDisappearAnimator(hover4, R.id.hover_play_video, Techniques.SlideOutLeft);

       }}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to sample of the library you should do the settings before onClick() happens. Like this:

```
BlurLayout.setGlobalDefaultDuration(450);
samplelayout = (BlurLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.blur_layout);
View hover4 = LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.hover_card_view, null);
samplelayout.setHoverView(hover4);
samplelayout.setBlurDuration(1000);
samplelayout.addChildAppearAnimator(hover4, R.id.hover_play_video, Techniques.SlideInRight);
samplelayout.addChildDisappearAnimator(hover4, R.id.hover_play_video, Techniques.SlideOutLeft);

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == slipImage.getId()) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Chapter =" + String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()+1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: then what's the use of library....i want that blur layout when the user clicks any of the item....look i have pasted a image link